# Jquery callback does not recognize jquery function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function making a AJAX get request and the callback setup to update the content of a div. The only problem is that within the callback function I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Object #HTMLDivElement has no method 'html'*

For some reason the jquery $("selector") is returning just the div not a jquery object.

Here's the code

```
//HTML
<select id="dimensions" name="dimensions" onchange="getDimention()">
    <option value="default">Select One</option>
....
</select>
 <div id="dim" > No Dimentions added yet</div>

//JS
function getDimention() {
   var eSelect = document.getElementById('dimensions');
  server.Dimention(eSelect.value, onGetDimentionSuccess); //make AJAX call
}
function onGetDimentionSuccess(response) {
   $('dim').html(response);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is loaded, try `jQuery('#dim').html(response);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have prototype or any other javascript framework running?

Try jQuery.noConflict() and then using jQuery('#dim').html

Comment: No I don't have prototype or any other JS framework running. But it does work with jQuery.noConflict();
       
       jQuery('#dim').html(response);  Thanks!!

Comment: @VinodKurpad: That means some other javascript library is loading itself into the $ variable after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Another option is to do remap jQuery into $ into a local context:

(function($){
...use $ like jQuery...
})(jQuery);

Comment: @VinodKurpad: are you aware that your getDimention function could be inhanced by jQuery? var eSelect = $('#dimensions').val()

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the proper CSS-like selector:

```
$('#dim').html(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean - you forgot the `#` for the id selector

```
$('#dim').html(response);
```

Comment: Tried that too, but that that returns with Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of null

Comment: are you running your code before the dom is loaded? that's what it seems like..  If you are then wrap the code in a document.ready function

Comment: I didn't bother with that because its a ajax call from the same page, the DOM isn't reloaded is it? I could give that a try too.

Comment: It shouldn't be reloaded.. but how is the ajax getting fired?  on page load? form submit? button click?

Answer (score 1):

Id has to be appended with a **#**

Try this

```
$('#dim').html(response);
```

ClassNames with a **.**

```
 $('.dim').html(response); // Id dim was a class name
```

Comment: Tried that too, with $('#dim') I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of null  The interesting part here is that if I set a textarea value it works.